# Issue in viewing double values

Tags: matlab, floating-point, double, number-formatting

I am having an issue with viewing double data in matlab console. Actually, I am importing a matrix from my data file. The value of a particular row and column was `1.543` but in the console when I use `disp(x)` where `x` is the matrix imported, it is showing as `1.0e+03 * 0.0002`. However, when I try to access that particular element in the matrix using `disp(x(25,25))` where `25` and `25` are the row and column numbers it is showing to be `1.543`. So I am confused. Any clarifications. It is just that when I print the whole matrix it is showing as  `1.0e+03 * 0.0002`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command should fix it. It is only a display issue, the precision of the actual values in the matrix are not affected:

```
format shortG
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens due to high dynamic range of your data.
Try for example :

```
 x = [10^-10 10^10];
 disp(x);
```

The result is:

> 1.0e+010 *
>      0.0000    1.0000

It *looks* like the first value is zero, but it isn't. It is almost zero compared to the second one. That is not surprising. Try to add to the big value the small one, and subtract, and you get zero. That is due to floating point arithmetic.The following expression is `true`

```
 isequal( (x(1)+x(2)) - x(2) , 0)
```

**What can be done?**

1) A really high dynamic range can cause troubles in any kind of computations. Try to understand where it came from, and solve the problem in a broader context.

2). You can try to set

```
 format long
```

It can improve the situation *visually* for some of the cases.